# How do I install the SQL ASCMDLETS module?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Ultimately trying to run Invoke-ASCmd in an Azure VM (Win Server 2012 R2)running SQL Server 2016.

When I run Import-Module ASCMDLETS I get the error: "no valid module file was found in any module directory"

It seems the .dlls should be created in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\SQLASCMDLETS folder, but I only have a \SQLPS folder.

From SQL Server Management Studio 17 onwards, the SQL Server PowerShell module is installed separately, however after following the steps here: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-ps-module). Even after doing the Install-Module -Name SQLServer I still did not get the relevant files so I could then Import-Module SQLASCMDLETS

I've installed SSMS and all client tools in the SQL Server installation. Still not there, where do I get it?

Comment: From [relevant MS Docs article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/powershell/analysis-services-powershell-reference): _Analysis Services PowerShell cmdlets are included in the SqlServer module._

Answer (score 3):

Try this from Windows Powershell Admin session:

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Force
Invoke-ASCmd -InputFile "MyDeployFile.xmla" -Server "asazure://MyRegion.asazure.windows.net/MyServer"
```

And make sure you have **Windows Powershell 5** as a minimum requirement.
You can get the latest version from this [official link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616)

Comment: I've got the latest version of PowerShell (5.1) and ran the below scripts: 

$PSVersionTable
Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Force
Import-Module SQLASCMDLETS. 

Name                           Value                                                                       
----                           -----                                                                       
PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1005                                                              

I still get the same error message: "no valid module file was found.."

Comment: Invoke-ASCmd is part of "SqlServer" Module. Why are you trying to Import SQLASCMDLETS. Did you try Invoke-ASCmd just after Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Force ?

Comment: To clarify, I came here from this code sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/powershell/invoke-ascmd-cmdlet. Which is now out of date (and causing this confusion). I am going to edit your answer and add the Invoke-ASCmd part for completion